# Compile and execute arbitrary Java string in Android

Tags: java, android, compilation, execute

Is there any way that I can execute arbitrary Java code from a `String` like `Sql.exect(String)`. Is there something like `Java.exect(String)`. Can anyone point me to a command or simple tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Janino`, take a look at here;

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home

Comment: is this work for android code like textviwe for example

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but maybe try to dig about this [Java 6 Compiler API](http://www.javabeat.net/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/)

Comment: does this work in android well for example i want
String s = "int y = 3+6;"
then something like Run(x)

Comment: Ok, It's not for Android. For that check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538537/compiling-string-as-code-during-runtime-on-android