# android- can i make the app to download newest source code and update itself?

Tags: android, dalvik

my app is sideloaded which means it is not on google play store. when it comes to update, it requires users to manually download the apk and replace the previous.

is it possible that I can have majority of my code on my server and have app to pull then update itself? app would only have limited code in order to pull source code from server and all the necessary settings/permissions in manifest. this way I'll not need to send out a new apk too often.

i found similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538537/compiling-string-as-code-during-runtime-on-android) and someone mentioned about dalvik, but I have no clue how those work...Can someone please tell me if this is doable? and with some examples.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible, it's just not easy. Will you be trying to do this even without user intervention? If so, that will be harder still.

Comment: yea...basically, i want my users able to update just like all other apps on playstore with auto-update checked.

Comment: do you have examples?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, do you want to simulate the [incremental update that the Play Store has](http://androidcommunity.com/google-play-store-incremental-smart-app-updates-now-live-20120816/)? Or do you want to have auto-update? Apparently these 2 things are related, but different.

Comment: i have no idea what incremental update is. I just want to have auto-update. the idea is for user to update to the newest version without doing anything.  just like auto-update with no new permissions.

Comment: sideloaded apps require user to download the apk then install. not a really ideal way for user to update

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604239/install-application-programmatically-on-android

Comment: I believe it is possible, but a bit tricky, to run downloaded classes.  However you would normally download dex code, not source!

Comment: @Ivica thanks for the help, but that is not what im looking for.

Comment: @ChrisStratton do you have an example? dex code is also what i heard. i found [dexmaker](https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) might be helpful but really no clue on how to use it...