# Dalvik runtime compiler or other way, to load class in runtime

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I need to load the class in the running application that if you do not recompile and reinstall and restart the entire application, and only ONE place that I develop. 
So i think about two ways:
1) Compile .java to .class on host, and send .class (java bytecode), which is unacceptable for dalvik VM, but java bytecode to dalvik bytecode runtime converter i don't found.
2) Send source code of class as string, and compile in runtime. But i found only dexmaker, which is mock generator, not string source compiler.

[Compiling String as Code during Runtime on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538537/compiling-string-as-code-during-runtime-on-android)

Is there any solution?

p.s. Sorry for my English.

Update: maybe i can dynamically load classes.dex and "instancing" (i don't know is this word exist) my class?

Comment: good luck with that. One other approach would be to send a script and integrate an interpretor in your app (JS (already included through webviews), python, ...)

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857807/ ?

Comment: The "dx" tool from the android sdk is the tool you can use to convert java bytecode to dalvik bytecode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DexClassLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) to load a `classes.dex` file. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857807/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-load-a-library-at-runtime-from-an-android-applicat) might help you as well.